# Single Camera + Laser Projector Triangulation

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

I want to combine a laser line projector (projects a laser plane) and a single web camera to determine the X, Y, Z position of the laser point. I am slightly confused as to how to use the fact that we know the plane of the laser to advantage.

I have the camera intrinsics, and I know that the the laser projector is at an offset of some distance from the camera (no rotation.)

Comment: can the laser projector tell you the distance from it to the laser point?

Comment: No, it cannot .

Comment: I think it may be possible if the size of laser point size can be precisely measured to determine its distance, otherwise you can not get the exact solution (x,y,z) but a relation between x,z and y,z since there is one dimension data missing.